# How to add dependencies to RabbitMQ plugin under umbrella

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

I am developing a simple `RabbitMQ` plugin and wondering how can I add a library ([`esaml`](https://github.com/mateuszkorszun/esaml)) to it as an external dependency? My first approach was to create wrapper (`esaml-wrapper`) for it inside umbrella dir, with the following files:

**Makefile:**

```
include ../umbrella.mk
```

**package.mk:**

```
APP_NAME:=esaml

UPSTREAM_GIT:=git@github.com:mateuszkorszun/esaml.git
UPSTREAM_REVISION:=2604e22d6150b6d9bdc467ef55621d4b84d8e761
RETAIN_ORIGINAL_VERSION:=true

INCLUDE_DIRS+=$(CLONE_DIR)

ORIGINAL_APP_FILE:=$(CLONE_DIR)/src/$(APP_NAME).app.src
DO_NOT_GENERATE_APP_FILE=true
```

and then in my plugin **package.mk**:

```
RELEASABLE:=true
DEPS:=rabbitmq-server rabbitmq-erlang-client esaml-wrapper
```

Now, when running `make run-in-broker` in my plugin it fails on resolving `esaml` dependencies:

```
Error: dependent plugins [cowboy] not found; used by [esaml].
```

Please advice how to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

esaml seems to depend on Cowboy right? If that's the case then make your wrapper depend on https://github.com/rabbitmq/cowboy-wrapper